# Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: php, sql, oracle, parentheses

I'm having a tough time solving this problem with my code. I'm still new to Oracle/PHP/SQL. I've tried a lot of solution and none of it is working. Here's the code and error.

```
$searchsql = "
    SELECT rm.room_ID, rm.room_no
      FROM bsi_room rm
     WHERE rm.roomtype_id = ".$roomTypeId."
           AND rm.capacity_id = ".$capcityid."".$extraSearchParam."
           AND rm.room_id NOT IN
                  (SELECT resv.room_id
                     FROM bsi_reservation resv, bsi_bookings boks
                    WHERE     boks.is_deleted = FALSE
                          AND resv.bookings_id = boks.booking_id
                          AND resv.room_type_id = ".$roomTypeId."
                          AND (('".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' BETWEEN boks.start_date AND DATE_SUB(boks.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                           OR (DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN boks.start_date AND DATE_SUB(boks.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))               OR (boks.start_date BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY))                         OR (DATE_SUB(boks.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' AND DATE_SUB('".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', INTERVAL 1 DAY))))";
```

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Well, like it says, your parentheses are mismatched. First get that query to any sql worksheet (you can use sqldeveloper for example), get it to work with some values, and only after that paste it to PHP and replace the constant values with `'".$var.'"`. By the way, familiarize yourself with prepared statements, you'll get hit by SQL injection one day if you write statements like that.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
AND (('".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."' BETWEEN boks.start_date AND DATE_SUB(boks.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))))
```

Should have 3 right parenthesis chars instead of 4. The subquery block ends too early.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I forgot to put to_date to all the date data types. Now its okay